# Django static files doesn't load on deployed server

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi

I use last versions of django, apache and mod_wsgi. I tried to deploy project on Ubuntu 16. The problem related to static files. They didn't load as shown in the figure below ([figure there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmX95.png)).
Actually, maybe I just don't see where I made a mistake, because I tried most things in the google and stackoverflow.

Code in the .conf file:

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/fpbg/media
Alias /static/ /var/www/fpbg/static

<Directory /var/www/fpbg/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/fpbg/static> # also I tried staticfiles
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Code in the settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
```

I executed manage.py collectstatic, It seems, I do everything, but it still doesn't work... HELP!

Comment: The Alias directive should point to the STATIC_ROOT, which ends in /staticfiles.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried it, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe reinstall Apache, because I have no hope for something else :D But if someone have idea, please, tell me, I'll be really thankful for any ideas.

Comment: It was necessary to add the slash in the end of staticfiles. Question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have trailing slash on the sub path. Instead of:

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/fpbg/media
Alias /static/ /var/www/fpbg/static
```

use:

```
Alias /media /var/www/fpbg/media
Alias /static /var/www/fpbg/static
```

By using what you had, for:

```
/static/foo.txt
```

it would be trying to find:

```
/var/www/fpbg/staticfoo.txt
```

and would fail.

The above presumes you have `STATIC_ROOT` matching and have run `collectstatic` as well.